# Why In oracle SQL the time taken to execute a query with two different values for the same column in where condition differs a lot

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

Let's say we have a table employee. I am executing below 2 queries on this table.

**Query 1**

```
select * from employee where email_id = 'admin@xyz.com'
```

**Query 2**

```
select * from employee where email_id = 'abc@xyx.com'
```

Assume I have a huge dataset on which I am executing this queries. Observation is Query1 takes very less time than Query2. I also checked there is no index on column email_id. My assumption is that the server is somehow caching Query1 and not Query2. If that is true then how can I force the server to cache Query2? Also, if possible I want to make Query2 optimized without using indexing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without an index on `email_id` we would expect both queries to take the same time, the time it takes to do a full table scan on the employees table. So why would one query return much faster than the other?

Assumptions:

1. Your queries really use hard-coded values rather then bind variables (i.e. *not* `select * from employee where email_id = ':1'`).
2. The more performative query really is searching for `admin` email address.

Queries that contain literals are usually a bad thing: each version has to be hard parsed, they take up space in the cursor cache. But they also may have different execution paths (because they are parsed separately) or performance profiles. That appears to be the case here. Without an index the access path will be the same, but the total elapsed time could be different due to caching.

There are two possible caches which might be in play.

1. Accidental caching. The block containing the `employee` record for `admin@xyz.com` is already in the DB Buffer Cache, so the query doesn't have to read the entire table.
2. Deliberate caching. There is some which queries employees by email address which uses [resultset caching](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_packages.htm#CIHBDCEF), and the `employee` record for `admin@xyz.com` is cached there.

So, two reasons why `admin@xyz.com` could be cached. Obviously the same could be true of any employee. But it seems likely that people will be looking for `admin@xyz.com` more often than for `joe.soap@xyz.com`. Quite simply, (without knowing your application or your data), the admin user is queried frequently so more likely to be in a cache than any other random user.

> "how can I force the server to cache Query2?"

If the `admin` user is cached accidentally - it's simply kept warm in the buffer because it's queried so often - there's really not much you can do. It's true that we can pin tables in memory but that's usually a bad idea. Most of the time the database is a better manager of its resources than we are: if blocks aren't kept in the DB Buffer Cache it's because they aren't used very often (assuming the DBC is sized correctly).

If your application is using resultset caching then you could explicitly retrieve the record for `abc@xyz.com`. But you can't do that for all the users, for the same reason as before: you don't want to pin records in memory if they're are used that often.

Which brings us to goals. What are you trying to optimize here? Access times for a sub-set of users/ Or access time for any user? If it's that latter, then you need an index on `email_id`.

Comment: Thank you, for mentioning the pros and cons of many approaches. The reason I was against indexing is that I wanted to optimize the query for a subset of users.

Answer (score 0):

More assumptions:

1. Once you run query2, it will be in your buffer cache, and the second time you run it you will have a cache hit, unless you run the query much later and it had aged out by then.
2. You are using cursor_sharing=FORCE which forces system binds
3. You have some really good reason not to use an index on email_id. You really, really want to make good use of indexes.
4. What about query3 and query4, etc. in future?

Comment: I accidentally pressed `enter` before completing by question 8-|

Comment: I pressed enter on purpose :)  Nice answer APC.  I upvoted.